# Does night takeoff and landing currency also count for daytime currency?

Tags: faa-regulations, far-61

My initial thought is that night currency satisfies daytime currency, but what gives me pause is [FAR 61.57(a)(2)](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFar.nsf/FARSBySectLookup/61.57) notes that a non-current pilot is allowed to conduct day VFR or day IFR flights without passengers to obtain currency.  There is no mention of night flight being allowed.  This seems to imply that day flights are required for daytime currency.

Comment: If you can do it at night, you can certainly do it during the day.  :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes**, night landings satisfy the requirements of §61.57(a)(1) for both nighttime and daytime currency.

The wording of the regulation is not crystal clear, and some (including me) have thought that the wording of (a)(2) required daytime landings for daytime currency. This is not the case, per the following interpretation from the FAA (Springfield, IL FSDO, dated 16 April 2014):

> Please note, in this section, there is no mention of a day or night differences in the regulation.
>
> In 14 CFR 61.57(b) the regulation specifically mentions the requirement for Night Takeoffs and Landings and the time period they can be completed in.   If the passenger carrying will be done at night, the additional requirements of 14 CFR 61.57(b) must be met.
>
> The night takeoffs and landings, as required by 14 CFR 61.57(b), will qualify for both the day and night requirement, provided all other requirements are met.   The day takeoffs and landings will NOT qualify for the night (section (b)) requirement though.
>
> Stanley E. Swank II
>   Aviation Safety Inspector
>   Springfield, IL FSDO, AGL-19

Other sources on the Internet agree with this interpretation:

- [Eric Gideon at askacfi.com](http://www.askacfi.com/342/can-night-currency-count-towards-day-currency.htm):

> ... your three takeoffs and landings to a full stop at night will also fulfill the recent flight experience requirements for day currency.

- [A thread at pilotsofamerica.com](http://www.pilotsofamerica.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27916).

Comment: The university library has FARs from that far back. I'll check later today and post what i find.

Comment: The askacfi post you quote was actually written by me. I stand by that interpretation, and I think that [Magnetoz's answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3399/39) in this topic is the correct interpretation. If there was a limitation on time of day to count for currency, that would've shown up in 61.57(a)(1).

Comment: [Here's a link to a google books archive of the 1990 FARs](http://books.google.com/books?id=2qI5AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA21&ots=Fk_5EveeeZ&dq=61.57%20night%201990&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q=61.57%20night%201990&f=false), which seems to support Magnetoz's perspective that (a)(2) is explicitly explaining how out-of-currency pilots may become current.

Comment: As promised:  http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3402/167

Comment: So, (a)(2) just specifies one way that the currency ***may*** be accomplished (notice the word *may* instead of *must* in the wording of the regulation).  (a)(1) specifically says that you must have "at least three takeoffs and three landings within the preceding 90 days" and doesn't specify that they must be during the day.

Comment: OK everyone, I have a response from the FSDO and I stand corrected. I have updated the answer accordingly and included the text of the FSDO's response. I'm sorry that my interpretation was wrong and hope no one was misled (though I tried to be fair, up-front and unbiased while I researched this); nevertheless I'm glad I now have a more or less definitive answer!

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, night landings count for day currency.

[61.57(a)(1)](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFar.nsf/FARSBySectLookup/61.57) explains:

> Except as provided in paragraph (e) of this section, no person may act as a pilot in command of an aircraft carrying passengers or of an aircraft certificated for more than one pilot flight crewmember unless that person has made at least three takeoffs and three landings within the preceding 90 days.

Period.  That's it.

Night currency limitations simply add an extra caveat to the above: you have to have done the landings to a full stop.

---

### But what about 61.57(a)(2)?  It clearly says day VFR or day IFR?

Your question is slightly misleading.  (a)(2) talks about how to regain currency after you've already lost it...and the quote in your question is incorrect.  You said this:

> a non-current pilot is allowed to conduct day VFR or day IFR flights without **passengers** to obtain currency

**No!**

The reg actually says:

> provided no persons or property are carried on board the aircraft, other than **those necessary** for the conduct of the flight.

A non-current pilot is allowed to act as pilot in command in order to become current, so long as nobody is carried other than those individuals who are necessary for the conduct of the flight.  Such as the first officer, a flight instructor, or an examiner.

---

### So why is there the day limitation?

*Because there's no restriction on multi-crew operations at night.*

61.57(a)(1)

> Except as provided in paragraph (e) of this section, no person may act as a pilot in command of an aircraft **carrying passengers or of an aircraft certificated for more than one pilot flight crewmember** unless that person has made at least three takeoffs and three landings within the preceding 90 days,

vs

61.57(b)(1)

> Except as provided in paragraph (e) of this section, no person may act as pilot in command of an aircraft **carrying passengers** during the period beginning 1 hour after sunset and ending 1 hour before sunrise, unless within the preceding 90 days that person has made at least three takeoffs and three landings to a full stop during the period beginning 1 hour after sunset and ending 1 hour before sunrise, and

If you need to get current in a multi-crew airplane, you can.  (a)(2) says so.  **You don't need to get current in a multi-crew airplane at night, because there's no restriction on multi-crew operations at night.**

Comment: @dvnrrs - No ambiguity that I can see.  (a)(1) answers the original question.  The rest of it is just confusion about multi-crew operations at night.

Comment: Per a response from my local FSDO, this answer (at least the portion stating that night landings count for day currency) is correct. I stand corrected and have updated my own answer below.

Comment: Your last sentence is incorrect if you have passengers on board for the flight. You would need to be night current for that because of the fact that you are carrying passengers, whether it is multi-crew or not.

Answer (score 3):

[FAR 61.57(a)(2)](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFar.nsf/FARSBySectLookup/61.57) is for the purpose of fulfilling (a)(1). Meaning, if you are out of day currency than you must make day landings.  If are day current, then night landings will qualify to continue your day currency.

Answer (score 0):

I just passed my PPL checkride a couple of weeks ago, and the examiner asked me this very question.  I said I'd have to look it up in the FAR, but as I started flipping pages he said don't bother... 3 full stop night landings do satisfy the requirements for day currency.